# How to control the width of custom labels in System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting?

Tags: .net, vb.net, charts

I have some code that produces a simple thermometer-like chart using an old Dundas charting component (ver 7).  Here is that code:

```
'Imports Dundas, Dundas.Charting, Dundas.Charting.WebControl
Public Shared Function GetSimpleThermometerChart(ByVal currentValue As Integer, ByVal goalValue As Integer) As Stream
    If goalValue < 0 Then goalValue = 0
    If currentValue < 0 Then currentValue = 0
    If currentValue > goalValue Then currentValue = goalValue

    Dim red = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 80, 77)
    Dim chart1 = New Chart()
    Dim series1 = chart1.Series.Add("Series1")
    Dim defaultArea = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Default")

    With chart1
        .Legends(0).Enabled = False
        .Height = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(200)
        .Width = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(275)
    End With

    With defaultArea
        .BorderStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid

        ' Y-axis
        .AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = True
        .AxisY2.Interval = goalValue / 2
        .AxisY2.Maximum = goalValue
        .AxisY2.LabelStyle.Interval = goalValue
        .AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Interval = goalValue / 2
        .AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
        .AxisY2.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10)
        .AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add((goalValue * 0.45), (goalValue * 0.55), String.Format(" You're half way to your goal of {0}!", goalValue))
        .AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add((goalValue * 0.9), (goalValue * 0.99), String.Format(" You met the goal of {0}!!!", goalValue))

        ' X-axis
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.Maximum = 1
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0.8
        .AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
    End With

    ' Populate series data
    Dim pt1 = New DataPoint(1, currentValue)
    series1.Points.Add(pt1)

    With series1
        .Type = SeriesChartType.Column
        .Color = red
        .YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
    End With

    Dim memStrm As New MemoryStream()
    chart1.Save(memStrm, ChartImageFormat.Png)
    memStrm.Position = 0
    Return memStrm
End Function
```

The chart produced by this code shows a nice, small graph on the left with the complete, un-truncated text of the custom label on the right Y-axis.

Microsoft bought and integrated the Dundas charting component into the .NET 4.0 framework, so I have been testing to see if the charts function the same way.  I, of course, instantly ran into inconsistencies.  In converting the code above to the new `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` equivalent, I wind up with the following code:

```
'Imports System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
Public Shared Function GetSimpleThermometerChart(ByVal currentValue As Integer, ByVal goalValue As Integer) As Stream
    If goalValue < 0 Then goalValue = 0
    If currentValue < 0 Then currentValue = 0
    If currentValue > goalValue Then currentValue = goalValue

    Dim red = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 80, 77)
    Dim chart1 = New Chart()
    Dim series1 = chart1.Series.Add("Series1")
    Dim defaultArea = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Default")

    With chart1
        .Height = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(200)
        .Width = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(275)
    End With

    With defaultArea
        '.InnerPlotPosition.Height = 100 ' YUCK!  Why???
        '.InnerPlotPosition.Width = 20  ' YUCK!  Why???

        .BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid

        ' Y-axis
        .AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = True
        .AxisY2.Interval = goalValue / 2
        .AxisY2.Maximum = goalValue
        .AxisY2.LabelStyle.Interval = goalValue
        .AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Interval = goalValue / 2
        .AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
        .AxisY2.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10)
        .AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add((goalValue * 0.45), (goalValue * 0.55), String.Format(" You're half way to your goal of {0}!", goalValue))
        .AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add((goalValue * 0.9), (goalValue * 0.99), String.Format(" You met the goal of {0}!!!", goalValue))

        ' X-axis
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.Maximum = 1
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0.8
        .AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
    End With

    ' Populate series data
    Dim pt1 = New DataPoint(1, currentValue)
    series1.Points.Add(pt1)

    With series1
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
        .Color = red
        .YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
    End With

    Dim memStrm As New MemoryStream()
    chart1.SaveImage(memStrm, ChartImageFormat.Png)
    memStrm.Position = 0
    Return memStrm
End Function
```

Now, instead of scaling the graph to display the full text of my custom label, the graph grows fatter and the text is truncated with an elipsis.  I've searched for how to get the behavior from Dundas with no luck.  I've tried various settings such as:

```
With defaultArea
   .AxisY2.IsLabelAutoFit = True
   .AxisY2.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.None
   .AxisY2.LabelStyle.TruncatedLabels = False
End With
```

These do not work.  The only thing I've seemed to be able to get to work is if I do this:

```
With defaultArea
   .InnerPlotPosition.Height = 100 ' YUCK!  Why???  Seems brittle...
   .InnerPlotPosition.Width = 20 ' YUCK!  Why???  Seems brittle...
End With
```

The trouble with this code is that I care more about the size of the text than I do about the size of the graph, and I expect the text to always show.  Though the text in this contrived example is hard-coded, in the real system it will not be so I really need the graph size to be dynamic so that the custom label always shows the text without scaling the font size.  Any suggestions for how to mimic the default behavior from the old Dundas component?

Answer (score 3):

I know what you mean by trying to find the *right* property to use with the MS Chart Controls. Walking the object hierarchy can be a pain, but I think what you are looking for is the following code:

```
Me.Chart1.ChartAreas("Default").AxisY2.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 6)
```

Comment: I've actually got the font set with this line - `.AxisY2.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10)`.  Trouble is, I don't want the font to shrink to fit, I'd prefer the graph to shrink.  If I let the font shrink, it does display the whole text, but there's plenty of room for the text at 10pt without the ellipsis if I could just shrink the graph.  I know this because the Dundas version works properly.